# Corrupt video duration after ffmpeg speeding up process

Tags: video, ffmpeg, timestamp

I'm using this code to speed up some videos:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "C:\Users\Agustín\Downloads\Presentación.mp4" -vf "setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/1.5" -crf 18 -af atempo=1.5 "C:\Users\Agustín\Downloads\Comercio\Presentación.mp4"
```

The first batch of videos turned out fine, but the second didn't: the descriptions of each video still have the original length and, when playing the videos, the time bar shows the original length. For example, when you play a video that was shortened to be 40 minutes, the bar keeps showing 1 hour as its length; after the 40 minutes, the video ends (no silent playing, it just stops and goes to 00:00).

I've found this post: https://superuser.com/questions/863183/how-to-fix-ffmpeg-inaccurate-time-stamp-that-corrupts-thumbnail-generation

The solution proposed was to copy the video and audio to a new container so the length would be reset...

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v copy -c:a copy output
```

... but it doesn't work with my videos.

I believe the problem lies in timestamps: the first batch of videos didn't have them, but this one does ("screen recording started", etc.). After speeding up the videos, timestamps were left unchanged (they don't correlate with the video that is faster now).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you try to reencode the videos, for example with `-c:v libx265` ?

Comment: Could there be a (silent) audio running past video re "when you play a 40 minutes video, there's a 1 hour bar; after the 40 minutes, the video ends"? Another possibility is that if there is a gap in timestamp, you could get behavior like that, but your first command should fix such issue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @mashuptwice. Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @kesh. Maybe I didn't express myself very clearly; I was giving an example to illustrate. I've edited the post to explain it better. There shouldn't be 20 minutes of silent audio afterwards, because the code speeds up both video and audio from 1 hour to 40 minutes. When the player reaches 40 minutes, the video ends (no silent playing, it just stops and goes to 00:00).

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to try:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf setpts=N/FR/1.5/TB -crf 18 -af atempo=1.5 output.mp4
```

If there is an issue with video timestamp that's causing the said behavior, using `(PTS-STARTPTS)/1.5` would not correct it. If this is the problem, though, it could mess up the audio sync. So, look for that.

If problem persists, probe the input/output files like so:

```
ffprobe -hide_banner -of default -show_format -show_streams input.mp4
```

and compare the durations of streams as well as the container's. If you need further help, post the output.

If nothing jumps out, then try encode only one stream at a time (use the `-an` output option to disable sound and `-vn` option likewise for video).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I've tried the first code but the result is the same. When I try probing with your second code, the following message appears: 

`Unrecognized option 'of'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found.`

This is what I've written:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" ffprobe -hide_banner -of default -show_format -show_streams "C:\Users\Agustín\Downloads\Comercio\Presentación original.mp4"`

Comment: wrong program. Try `ffprobe`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! Now it works, but this appears in both cases (input and output): `Unsupported codec with id 98314 for input stream 2`. The duration stays the same for both...